# WCF, Data-Updates & EntityReference object could not be serialized

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, .net-4.0, self-tracking-entities

I did a lot of stuff with WCF where I first thought: "Hmm, this problem is weird" - but after I figured each one out, it always made somehow sense (sometimes more, sometimes less).
But now I'm at a point where I'm stuck and with all my imagination, I cannot think of a reason why this error appreas:

> The EntityReference object could not be serialized. This type of object cannot be serialized when the RelationshipManager belongs to an entity object that does not implement IEntityWithRelationships.

To put it in a context, let me tell you about my program in a nutshell:
I have a client which send's an ID to my WCF.
If this ID is in use, I'll grab it's related object from the EF (otherwiese I'll create a new one) and send it back.

This all is done by Selftracking Entities - and getting the objects works fine, as well as the first update:

```
public static void UpdatePaperOnServer(ref PAPER p)
{
    var newP = ServiceClient.UpdatePaper(p);
    p = newP;
}
```

The reference "p" is a field in < Program > and any changes will happen on this variable.

Here is the server-side implementation of UpdatePaper.
As you can see, no magic will happen here neither:

```
public PAPER UpdatePaper(PAPER p)
{
    p.ChangePaperOnDb(); //Simple static DAL-Accessor, works fine

    return p; //The Client should get any changes made by other users so far, that's why I'll give the obj back... or if it's a new obj and it has an ID now
}
```

As I said, my first Update works fine, but as soon as I trigger the update-routine again, I'll get this error which I mentioned above.

After spending some time with my good mate google, I found only an approach where they changed the .NET-Version from 4.0 to 3.5.
But I don't know if that would for me as I can't change the runtime from 4.0 to 3.5.

If anyone has any clue what's going on - please let me know.
Thank you very much!